# Dominant and Monotone Convergence With Expectation

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

[image]

[image]

I've tried dotting around this article to little avail:

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XiPK6p2U0EQC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=limn%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E+E%5BXn%5D+%3D+E%5BX++implies&source=bl&ots=W0GUmbQ_XA&sig=QLo3f7c5b9AQbblwAvJFC6otB-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAzgKahUKEwjnkp3arMTIAhVH2hoKHconB90#v=onepage&q=limn%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E%20E%5BXn%5D%20%3D%20E%5BX%20%20implies&f=false.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|X-X_n| = X_n-X +2(X-X_n)^+$, and the non-negative random variable $(X-X_n)^+$ is dominated by $X$. (Here $b^+:=\max(b,0)$.) I'm guessing that you are to assume that $\Bbb E[X]<\infty$.

Comment: $E|X-X_n| = E(X_n)-E(X) +2E(X-X_n)^+$,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}E|X-X_n| = \lim_{n\to\infty}E(X_n)-E(X) +2\lim_{n\to\infty}E(X-X_n)^+$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}E|X-X_n| = E(X)- E(X) + 2E\lim_{n\to\infty}(X-X_n)^+$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}E|X-X_n| = 2\lim_{n\to\infty}E(X-X_n)^+$

...?

Comment: Now compute the pointwise limit $\lim_n (X(\omega)-X_n(\omega))^+$.

Comment: Since $(X-X_n)^+$ is dominated by $X$, $\lim_n E (X(\omega)-X_n(\omega))^+ = -\lim_{n\to\infty}E(X_n)+E(X)=0$?

Comment: Not quite. Remind yourself of the statement of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: http://imgur.com/JHe3bZ3 I've tried following this with $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$??

Comment: Is this the right way?